# Closure of the set of non-negative functions in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be  a  measure  space  and  suppose  that  there  is  a  set $A\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $0<\mu(A)<\infty$.  Let $H=L^2(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be the real Hilbert space of real-valued functions $f$ on $X$.  Consider the set $N=\{f\in H:f(x)\geq 0 \,\, \textrm{for almost every} \,\, x\in X\}$.

Prove that $N$ is closed in $H$.

Here is my attempt:

Let $f_n\to f$ in $H$ and suppose for contradiction that $\mu(\{ x\in X : f(x)<0\})>0$. Since $\{x \in X : f(x)<0\} = \bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}}\{x\in X : f(x)<-\frac{1}{k}\}$ there is some $k$ such that $K=\{x\in X : f(x)<-\frac{1}{k} \}$ has positive measure. Hence
\begin{align}
& \int_X |f_n-f|^2 \, d\mu \geq \int_K |f_n-f|^2 \, d\mu \\[8pt]
\geq {} & \int_K \left|0-\left(-\frac 1 k \right)\right|^2 \, d\mu = \frac 1 {k^2} \mu(K) \,\, \text{ for all} \,\, n\in \mathbb{N}
\end{align}
so $f_n\not\to f$ in $H$. This is a contradiction, hence $\mu(\{x \in X : f(x)<0\})=0$ and $f\in N$.

Is this correct?

Comment: This seems correct, although the step $\int_K |f_n-f|^2d\mu\geq \int_K |0-(-\frac{1}{k})|^2d\mu$ is a bit too quick to my taste

Comment: How do you justify $\int_K\, \vert f_n - f\vert^2\, d\mu \geq \int_K\, \vert 0 - (-1/k)\vert^2\, d\mu$? Oops, SolubleFish noticed the same thing.

Comment: My justification is just that $f_n\in N$ so $f_n\geq0$ and $f<-\frac{1}{k}$ on $K$. Am I missing something?

Comment: If $f_n\geq 0$ and $f<1/k$, then $f_n - f\geq 1/k\geq 0$. Therefore, $|f_n-f|^2 \geq 1/k^2$. I think it is best to add a few steps here in your proof

Comment: @SolubleFish Do you mean $f<-1/k$? If so is my justification correct? Because it seems to me that what you wrote is the same as what I wrote.

Comment: your proof is correct

Comment: I meant $f<-1/k$. Your proof is correct, it is just this one step which might deserve a little bit more detail to be perfectly clear and understandable